# UWP Store 0x800701C5

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps

I wrote a UWP program and I used Restricted capability

`broadFileSystemAccess`

When I published this application I obtained permission from Microsoft, and its now in the Microsoft Store.

[image: My App]

But when I tried to install it, it got an error:

[image: Error]

My computer: Windows 10 1809

I have tried googling this, and writing to Microsoft, both without finding a positive result.

Comment: Do you try to install it on the same computer you developed your app? If yes try to uninstall it first and then install the one from the Microsoft Store.

Comment: @IvanIčin Other people who use that access are all normal, so I think it is something wrong in my code. I just want know what should I do or what details I have not been found. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @MichalKania I tried three computer, always get this error

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the problem is actually only with your app by trying to install some other app if that will work.

If this happens only with your app, you should definitely contact [Windows developer support](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support) for this issue. Select **Contact us** tab, then **Windows 10 UWP app development** and submit your incident. They should be able to help. You can also post the problem on the [publishing Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-us/home?forum=wpregister%2Cwindowsstore%2Cwpsubmit%2Cwppayout%2Cwpdcapp%2Caiaads%2Caiasdk%2Caiamgr%2Cdcefi&filter=alltypes&sort=lastpostdesc) for greater visibility.

[image: Posting incident]

Comment: I already sent an email to Microsoft, but I didn't got any useful info......they always said:"Our engineering team and I are still in the process resolving your issue. I will provide an update as soon as possible"

Comment: Hopefully they will. But post the problem on the forums as well

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I just hope they will help me.

Comment: @haihanjin Did you get an answer from MS?

Comment: This problem is still relevant

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to ensure to reference:

```
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap"
```

and:

```
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: If you cannot answer without a clarification question, i.e. if this is meant to be a comment, please deletet this, find some other question to answer first and then, when you got your commenting privilege ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ) come back here. If you do mean this to be an answer according to [answer] please [edit] to make that more obvious, e.g. by describing the effect of what you propose and explaining why thtat solves the problem.